# Bind same function to different classes in meteor template event

Tags: templates, events, meteor

Is there a way to bind more than one event/class to a function in meteor template events map?

Something like this:

```
Template.template_name.events(
{
    'click .class1 .class2 h1': function (event, template)
     {
          alert("click");
     }
 }
```

doesn't work

Comment: Be careful with such placement of curly braces! In Javascript, it matters, and may result in broken code. First hit in Google: http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experience with meteor, the correct syntax is :

```
Template.templateName.events({
    "event1 cssSelector1, ..., eventN cssSelectorN":function(event,template){
    }
});
```

Warning : the space between the comma and the next event DOES matter.

So in your example, you might come up with something like :

```
Template.template_name.events({
    "click .class1, click .class2, click h1":function(event,template){
    }
});
```